# Flink capture messages based on time window and process

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to calcualate and process the message using flink. here flink is reading data from kafka, my requirement is I read and process data between time frame.
eg.

messages between 12:00 to 12:30,

message  between 12:30 to  1:00.. and so on,

I am totally new to flink can you guide or suggest any help, document on this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windowing is explained on this page : https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/windows.html

Concretely, it will look like this (as an example) :

```
val windowing: DataStream[(**,**,...)] = data
  .keyBy(?)
  .timeWindow(Time.minutes(30))
  .map ( // your mapping )
  .reduce ( // your reduce function here )
```